# How to include syntax extensions in your _oasis file? I'm trying to use deriving-ocsigen.syntax in my project

Tags: ocaml

Here is my current _oasis file:

```
OASISFormat: 0.3
Name:        testing syntax
Version:     0.1
Synopsis:    testing
Authors:     Johnathan Doeman
License:     GPL-3

Executable testmain
  Path:       ./
  BuildTools: ocamlbuild
  BuildDepends: batteries, deriving-ocsigen, deriving-ocsigen.syntax
  MainIs:     main.ml
```

Note that ocsigen-deriving seems to be properly installed on my system. I am able to use it in the toplevel after the correct #requires. I'm also using oasis version 0.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way in Oasis 0.3, which I haven't switched to yet, but previously you had to include this in your _tags file (outside the part auto-generated by oasis):

```
<*.ml>: syntax_camlp4o
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish, this seems to work out for me. I too have heard that oasis 0.3 should have support for this stuff but could not find/understand the documentation for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put this information into _tags file?

AFAIR after `oasis setup' oasis  rewrites only a part of _tags file, user-written part it lets as-is.

Answer (score 0):

It's not (yet) supported; see https://forge.ocamlcore.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1050&group_id=54&atid=291